# Make over scroll glow be outside the padding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-view, android-scrollview

I have the following:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

I add this for a cleaner UI:

```
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
```

However, now the scroll bar is inside the padding and looks funky. So I add:

```
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
```

The scroll bar is now outside the padding, however, the over scroll glow is still inside the padding.

**How do I get the over scroll glow to stretch across the padding?**

EDIT:

Here's the full layout code that encounters the same issue as above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: Can you please share your full xml code.

Comment: @MayurPatel added my code to the question.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">


</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>`

Comment: @stacksonstacks i think this not your question. right?

Answer (score 17):

What you need to do is to apply `android:clipToPadding="false"` to `RecyclerView`. Consider this xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="40dp"
    android:paddingBottom="40dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"/>
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to put padding inside RecyclerView's item layout and not on RecyclerView itself.

However, you could just use margins and the glow should stay inside the RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

While the answer given by @azizbekian works, it's also possible to set `clipToPadding` programmatically.

In Kotlin: `recyclerView.clipToPadding = false`

In java: `recyclerView.setClipToPadding(false)`

My personal favorit is to extend RecyclerView and set a `LayoutManager`, `clipToPadding` and such in the init function (constructor).

Comment: I believe everything (mostly everything) that is possible to specify in `xml` has appropriate API to refer from Java/Kotlin code.